# How can I tell which filesystem Worklight's <app-deployer> is referring to?

Tags: deployment, ant, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using [Worklight's](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/worklight) automated  ANT task to deploy a Worklight application. Unfortunately, it's currently failing with this error message:

```
BUILD FAILED
/deployment/jenkins/jobs/UAT-uat2-Deploy/workspace/co.uk.homebase.strategic-app/Homebase/ciBuild/buildAndDeployAnt.xml:171: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/deployment/jenkins/jobs/UAT-uat2-Deploy/workspace/co.uk.homebase.strategic-app/Homebase/ciBuild/buildAndDeployAnt.xml:186: app-deployer failed:SEVERE:Bad Request; Error 400: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: There is not enough space in the file system.
```

Unfortunately, the error message isn't precise about *which* filesystem is out of space. On this system, there are several filesystem which might be relevant, including `/tmp`, the Liberty server install filesystem (our Worklight server is running on WebSphere Liberty), and a separate filesystem for the Worklight logs.

Is there any way we can discover which filesystem is being referred to? None of them appear to be significantly low on space, although the /tmp filesystem is quite small, so that's my suspicion. If that's the case, is there a way to configure  to use a different filesystem for temporary files?

Comment: Setting a different temp folder in your operating system does not sound like something Worklight (nor ANT) needs to handle...

Comment: @IdanAdar, I agree. Do you know which filesystem it's referring to though? The system we are running the ANT task on? The one we are deploying to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, we discovered that the filesystem that was out-of-space was on the *target* system where we were trying to deploy a `.wlapp` file. Doubling the size of `/tmp` (this was an AIX box) fixed the issue.