# MobileFirst app build - failed creating temporary directory to build adapter

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I have working command line build setup for my MobileFirst application. However today when I ran a build, I got following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\...\build.xml:29: Failed creating temporary directory to build adapter
```

What might be the cause of this error?

I'm running the build via ant:

```
ant build
```

Relevant part of build.xml is:

```
<target name="build">
    <app-builder worklightserverhost="${server.address}" applicationFolder="apps/MyApp" outputFolder="${build.dir}"/>
    <adapter-builder folder="adapters/Adapter1" destinationFolder="${build.dir}" />
    <adapter-builder folder="adapters/Adapter2" destinationFolder="${build.dir}" />
...
</target>
```

Build jar files are correctly included in build.xml. I'm operating on MobileFirst 7.0.

Comment: Maybe your temp directory is full?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755777/how-can-i-tell-which-filesystem-worklights-app-deployer-is-referring-to

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. However I'm working on single-drive Windows 7 workstation with enough space. System temp directories cleared, no other limitations I'm aware of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by referencing nonexistent adapter. I removed one of deprecated adapters from the project but forget to edit build.xml file.