# Any way to write Ant Script to enter multiple input from directory and run them in parallel

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to write a script which takes input from directory all the adapters and build the adapters in parallel. I just want a generic script which works with every mobile first code to build adapters.

```
<target name="build-adapter">
<dirset id="check" dir="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/adapters"     includes="*"/>
<property name="test" refid="check"/>
<echo>${test}</echo>
<parallel>
  <adapter-builder
    folder="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/adapters/${test}"
    destinationfolder="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/bin"
classpathref="base.path"/>
</parallel>

</target>
```

I is throwing following error..

> Failed creating temporary directory to build adapter.

Comment: Where exactly does it take $test from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its got fixed. I used below code to complete the objective.

```
<target name="build-adapter-parallel">
    <for param="check" parallel="true">
        <path>
        <dirset dir="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/adapters" includes="*"/>
    </path>      
<sequential>
<echo> value of @{check}</echo>
    <adapter-builder
    folder="@{check}"
    destinationfolder="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/bin"
     classpathref="base.path"/>
 </sequential>
 </for>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error likely because the task didn't find any adapters. I don't think you can do * to find all adapters.

Perhaps you could supply a list of adapters/paths and use a FOR loop:

- http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html
- http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/01/03/apache-ant-for-loop-example-for-reading-a-text-file/

Comment: thanks for reply. if  I use for loop then i won't able to build adapter in parallel. this script is able to find all the adapters but in test name of all adapters it is taking at once. I want it to take replicate itself so that i would able to perform parallel build.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does following:

1. puts semicolon-separated list of paths to `${test}`
2. builds single adapter of name `${test}` (`/../Adapter1;/../Adapter2`)
3. such an adapter does not exist, that is indicated by confusing error message with directory creation ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619382/mobilefirst-app-build-failed-creating-temporary-directory-to-build-adapter/30641417#30641417))

I believe [for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) of ant-contrib with `parallel="true"` flag is your friend

**Edit:**
Ant tasks which work for me:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
<target name="build-adapter">
    <echo>building adapter: ${adapter.path}</echo>
    <basename property="adapter.name" file="${adapter.path}"/>
    <adapter-builder folder="adapters/${adapter.name}" destinationfolder="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="build-adapters">
    <foreach param="adapter.path" parallel="true" target="build-adapter">
        <path>
            <dirset dir="adapters" includes="*"/>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

Notes:

- parallel="true" does not work along with for, at least with my ant-contrib-0.6 (foreach used instead so second target created)

Comment: Filip <target name="build-adapter2">
        <for param="check" parallel="true">
            <path>
            <dirset dir="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/adapters" includes="*"/>
        </path>      
 <sequential>
   <echo> value of ${check}</echo>
        <adapter-builder
        folder="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/adapters/${check}"
        destinationfolder="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace1/MyTime/bin"
         classpathref="base.path"/>
     </sequential>
     </for>
    </target> I used this code it is throwing error.

Comment: Hi kiran, I prepared targets which work. Two things had to be done: 1) foreach instead of for, it seems that parallel="true" does not work now with for 2) basename used to cut adapter name from path.

Comment: Filip "parallel=true" works for "FOR". I did it. It doesn't work for "foreach".

Comment: According to documentation, it should work for both. However my experience is opposite to yours.